# SSH login keeps kicking me out

Tags: centos, ssh, profile, node.js, rvm

I am on Centos 6.6 and recently updated my server using yum, it updated a bunch of things and everything seemed fine, but I was also trying to update Ruby RVM and Node.js and NPM (Node Package Manager)... Got a weird error, when I exited as root, then when I logged out and tried to log back in I am now getting this:

```
Seans-Laptop:~ zweb$ ssh zweb@XX.XX.XX.XX
zweb@50.56.34.89's password:
Last login: Sat Nov 21 05:25:44 2015 from c-XX-XX-XX-XX.hsd1.ca.comcast.net
ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!
Connection to XX.XX.XX.XX closed.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?  I tried to disable loading the .bash_profile when logging in but that didn't work.  I can't SSH into my server at all now from both root and my user account.

All of my websites are still up and running, but I can't login or SFTP to work on them.

Comment: It might be this bug: https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/2385. Obtained by googling the error. Do you have RVM installed on the server? And do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: Unfortunatly I do not have physical access to the server, it's a VPS on Rackspace... Seems I am completely locked out.

Comment: I suggest contacting Rackspace and getting them to help you.

Comment: Ok, I am now able to login through SSH, just needed to do ^C right after entering my password... Now just need to figure out how to fix the 'which' command error.

Answer (score 1):

OK - here's the quick and dirty on how I fixed it.

Basically, after getting into the shell using the ^C trick (after you press enter on your password when ssh-ing in, your immediately press control-C).

Since I'm on Centos, I just did "yum remove which"... then "yum install which".

then I removed and re-installed ruby, nodejs and npm.